# Ruby on Rails Query: Joining tables and selecting multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-4

There are two models: microposts and users

**"microposts"** contains 4 columns: name, type, user_id and id

**"users"** contains 4 columns: name, type, address and id

Microposts belongs to users; users contains many microposts.

I want to find how many microposts each user has but for some reason, I cannot get the query to work properly.

The query I tried is:

```
User.joins(:microposts).group("users.id").select("users.*, count(microposts.id) as postcount")
```

This only pulls the attributes from the users table, but excludes the columns from the micropost table and also excludes the count column i created.

For some reason,

```
User.joins(:microposts).group("users.id").count
```

works but it only returns the user.id along with the count. I want to pull the other columns as well.

I also tried using "includes" instead of "joins", but that just returns all the columns of the users table and none from the microposts table.

```
User.includes(:microposts).group("users.id").select("users.*, count(microposts.id) as postcount")
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need both `joins` *and* `includes`, I think.

```
User.joins(:microposts).
  includes(:microposts).
  group("users.id").
  select("users.*, count(microposts.id) as postcount")
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you intend to use it?

If you want to loop over users and display both user attributes and it's microposts you can simply do this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.microposts.size %>
  <%= other_user_attributes %>

  <%= user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <%= micropost_attributes %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

P.s. If you also want micropost attributes returned you can do so in your select query. If you add 'microposts.title as micropost_title' it will return the micropost title as well. However, that makes no sense if you group based on the user id since one user can have multiple microposts.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to create an instance variable that has the count of microposts by user id. I need this to create several tables in the views file. Is there a way to modify the query to get the count as a column?